# Dynamic _url from rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my app engine I can reference:

```
engine_name.app_integration_stripe_url
```

And the correct url is returned. I'd like at some point to generate this URL dynamically based on the integration being configured. This is what I thought would work, but this throws an error:

```
  integration_key = 'stripe'
  route_name = "app_integration_#{integration_key}_url".to_sym
  redirect_to engine_name.method(route_name).call(query_params)
```

> undefined method app_integration_stripe_url for class
>   ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy

How can I generate one of these URLs dynamically?

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but you could probably use something like:
eval("engine_name.app_integration_" + integration_key + "_url")

Comment: or something like this :  redirect_to engine_name.send(route_name,query_params)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method` didn't seem to be the right, um, method, to call. Swapping for `send` lead me to the correct output without error:

```
route_name = "app_integration_#{integration_key}_url".to_sym
redirect_to doki_core.send(route_name, query_params)
```